# Where can I find Cypher Grammar specification?

Tags: cypher

As a part of my assignment at the University I have to go trough Cypher specification. The link on [openCypher site](https://opencypher.org/resources/) is broken. Is this what is [published on gihhub](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/tree/master/grammar) current version of openCypher specification? I don't see the version denoted anywhere.

Comment: Which link is broken? "[Cypher Query Language Reference (Version 9)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/openCypher9.pdf) containing the complete reference for Version 9 of the Cypher query language" loads just fine for me

Comment: The link for the grammar is broken. @Knittl has posted the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name in the grammar link has not been updated to M19, like all the other links.

It should be https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/M19/grammar-M19.zip.

<s>You should inform the openCypher project so that it can be fixed.</s> I have created a pull request to fix the links: https://github.com/opencypher/website/pull/27

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've been looking for.