# Is Memgraph following openCypher specification?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

I've taken a look at [openCypher specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73867156/where-can-i-find-cypher-grammar-specification). And I wonder if I can use all of the clauses any principles from openCypher in Memgraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph follows openCypher specifications, but there are some minor differences in implementation. You can find the exact list of differences listed on the [Memgraph documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/differences) site.